# full screen layout in Scroll View

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I want to have 2 layouts inside ScrollView. First layout should be on the full screen and second layout below first one. When activity starts it is not possible see second layout. Second layout is possible see after scroll screen. Please take a look on my image for better understand.

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Layout code: `

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- this layout can be any height you want -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>`
```

Get the device screen height:

        `Point size = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        int screenHeight = size.y;`

Find the LinearLayout:

        `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout1);`

Set the height of the layout based on the screen height you got earlier:

        `LayoutParams params = layout.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = screenHeight - getStatusBarHeight();`

Done. Be sure to call all of those methods in your onCreate method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, works perfect on the first time! I would like show emphasize this code for another people read this question [get the height of the status bar](http://mrtn.me/blog/2012/03/17/get-the-height-of-the-status-bar-in-android/). Then just change codeline `params.height = screenHeight - getStatusBarHeight()`

Comment: It does works !!! (welcome to Android - simple task insanely complicated).

Comment: Is there a solution in Kotlin? Also is there a solution where everything is done in .xml files only?